# How to stop webpages opening in new tabs when clicking on links on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First time poster here, learning the ropes with HTML/CSS/Javascript but a pretty big novice right now so seeking some help if possible. :-)

Myself and my co-founder have created a website through SAAS, and on the whole really like the function of the options offered - but... There's one irritating feature which we can't get our heads round how to solve (despite seeming simple).

Link to the site: thedinnertable.arcadier.io

In our footer, we have 'About Us', 'Terms of Service', 'Privacy Policy', 'FAQ' and 'Contact Us'. However, whenever you click on any of the options it opens it up into another tab. Similarly, in this new tab, there's a row of the different options at the top of the webpage, but whenever you click on them it again opens new tabs for each new option.

We really want to change this, but couldn't figure out the JS behind it, so got into contact with the service providers who provided the following JS as a guide on how to change it:

```js
$(".footer-navigation ul li:nth-child(4) a").attr("target", "");

function waitForElement(elementPath, callBack) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($(elementPath).length) {
      callBack(elementPath, $(elementPath));
    } else {
      waitForElement(elementPath, callBack);
    }
  }, 500)
}

$('.item-details .description-text .checkin_time').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text.replace('AM', 'uur'));
});

$('.item-details .description-text .checkout_time').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text.replace('PM', 'uur'));
});

$('.item-details .description-text .normal-black-text').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text.replace('AM', 'uur'));
});

$('.item-details .description-text .normal-black-text').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(text.replace('PM', 'uur'));
});

waitForElement('.purchase-hist-tbl-inner', function() {
  $('.purchase-hist-tbl-inner .booking-hide-on-wholeday').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('am', 'uur'));

    $('.purchase-hist-tbl-inner .booking-hide-on-wholeday').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(text.replace('am', 'uur'));
    });

    $('.purchase-hist-tbl-inner .booking-hide-on-wholeday').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(text.replace('pm', 'uur'));
    });

    $('.purchase-hist-tbl-inner .booking-hide-on-wholeday').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(text.replace('pm', 'uur'));
    });
  })

  waitForElement('.purhstdtls-delvry-sec', function() {
    $('.purhstdtls-delvry-sec .purhstdtls-delvry-method ul li li').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(text.replace('AM', 'uur'));
    });

    $('.purchase-hist-tbl-inner .booking-hide-on-wholeday').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(text.replace('PM', 'uur'));
    });
  })

  $(".page-search .item-list-section .item-sorting-option select `option[value='nearest']").remove();


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', ' .spacetime_tab-content .btn-tab-validate', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var $tab = $this.parents('.tab-pane');
      var $li = $tab.parents('li');

      //assume validation done after 700ml seconds 
      setTimeout(function() {

        if ($tab.find('.error-con').length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $li.offset().top
          }, 2000);

        }
      }, 700);
    });
  });
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to change it so it simply reloads the webpage and keeps it in the same tab instead? Reading that script to me doesn't seem like it has what we need to change, but the service providers insist it is.

Sorry to be a pain with this, we're just completely stuck with it and reading other similar questions hasn't made it any clearer unfortunately. :(

I wanted to include some pictures, but it won't let me yet as I'm new to the forum.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML You can use as below
`target="_self" href="https://www.youtube.com"`

Answer (score 0):

In your footer HTML code you have `target="_blank"` attribute on your action link tags.

The first line in the script changes FAQ link target attribute to empty, `$(".footer-navigation ul li:nth-child(4) a").attr("target", "");`.

You can change it to `$(".footer-navigation ul li a").attr("target", "");` to get the results you want.

I recommend changing it in the `HTML` code since it is way more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that's worked for the footer links, but when you click on the links in the footer, it takes you to a separate webpage where the same problem is still happening on the menu navigation. So, for example, you click on 'About Us', it takes you to the 'About Us' webpage whereby it then has a row of the footer links all at the top. If you click on these it opens them in other tabs. Sorry to be a pain - I've had a play around and I've not worked it out, do you have any tips?

Comment: I would recommend to remove all target attributes from the <a /> in the HTML code, but if you want to do it with javascript you can change the line to $("a").attr("target", ""); and make sure that the script is referenced on every page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's worked! Really appreciate your help.